# This is not a Wordle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordle

> Wordle 539 X/6
>
> [image]

**The answer is a common 6-letter word.**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The correct answer is

> LETTER

Step 1:

> Each row corresponds to a five letter word relating all the words in the row. They are: 
>  VINYL (vinyl group, vinyl record, etc.) 
>  SCENE (crime scene, nativity scene, etc.) 
>  BROWN (brown dwarf, brown bear, etc.) 
>  VISTA (Windows Vista, Toyota Vista, etc.) 
>  HOTEL (hotel rating, Hôtel-Dieu, etc.) 
>  ROMEU (Oriol Romeu, Romeu Zema, etc.)

Step 2:

> Using the colors in the grid, use the set of five letter words to solve a Wordle: 
>  [image: solved wordle game] 
>  Solving the Wordle gives the word [MASYU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masyu), a type of logic puzzle.

Step 3:

> Using the key G=B, Y=W, the grid of words becomes a Masyu grid, where the green words are black circles (G=B) and the yellow words are white circles (Y=W).
>  [image: unsolved masyu board] 
>  Solving the Masyu puzzle gives us this: 
>  [image: solved masyu board]

Step 4:

> If we impose the masyu solution path onto the Wordle grid, we get: 
>  [image: masyu solution path on Wordle grid] 
>  The 6 letters which were not intersected by the path spell the answer, LETTER.